# Using redux saga with a generic function

Tags: typescript, redux-saga

I am trying to make a saga generator that takes a generic function but am stuggling with the typing.

```js
function* test<T, Fn extends (input: T) => any>(fn: Fn, input: T) {
  const data = yield call(fn, input)
  yield put(putAction(data))
}
```

Here I get an error on the `yield`: 'yield' expression implicitly results in an 'any' type because its containing generator lacks a return-type annotation

So, I try to assign the return type:

```js
function* test<T, Fn extends (input: T) => any>(
  fn: Fn,
  input: T,
): Generator<StrictEffect, void, any> {
  const data = yield call(fn, input)
  yield put(putAction(data))
}
```

Now I get an error on `input` in the `call()`: Argument of type '[T]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Parameters'.

That one has me really confused. I get the same error on `input` if I try to specify the expected return type from yield:

```js
function* test<T, Fn extends (input: T) => any>(fn: Fn, input: T) {
  const data: SagaReturnType<Fn> = yield call(fn, input)
  yield put(putAction(data))
}
```

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong here?